# Error: Cannot convert from Double** to Double

Tags: c++, double

I am trying to make a function for my convex hull project, 
Calipers(). I tried creating a class for the points but
I cannot seem to use points to extract a value from p[].x into rotatingPoint.x
Thank you.

```
#include "point.h"

void Point::Set_value(Point p)
{

    x=p.x;                       
    y=p.y; 

}

void Point::Set_value(double nx,double ny)
{
    x=nx;
    y=ny;
}

void comp_geo::Calipers(int n, Point *p)
{
        double Cx = &p[n].x;
        double Cy = &p[n].y;
        rotatePoint.x = Cx;
        rotatePoint.y = Cy;

}
```

Calipers() does not work.

Comment: What part of "cannot convert from Double ** toDouble" you didn't understand? What do you expect to accomplish by attempting to assign a pointer to a `double`?

Comment: The whole part. Hence the question.

If I used `*p[n].x` it tells me to use <-
When I use it, it tells me I'm not using it properly.

Comment: There's no such thing "<-" in C++, so it is logically impossible for the compiler to tell you to do that. If you do not understand something, the correct approach is not to try making random changes to the code, crossing your fingers, and hope that it works somehow. The correct approach is to review your C++ book, and try to understand ***why*** you are getting the compilation error. Once you understand the root cause, you will then know what needs to be done to fix it.

Comment: EXACTLY. Hence I was scratching my head for an hour because I was googling the wrong thing.

If I do not understand something, the correct approach is asking a question. It isn't because I am lazy, it is how people learn.
Thanks for your input.

ALSO yes, I know the operation symbols * = for the value, &= for the address. I looked up how to interact with Class. Chill out on "Go back to the books scrb".

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the `&` operator:

```
void comp_geo::Calipers(int n, Point *p)
{
    double Cx = p[n].x;
    double Cy = p[n].y;
    rotatePoint.x = Cx;
    rotatePoint.y = Cy;`
}
```

Which can be simplified to this:

```
void comp_geo::Calipers(int n, Point *p)
{
    rotatePoint.x = p[n].x;
    rotatePoint.y = p[n].y;
}
```

Or even this (assuming `rotatePoint` is a `Point`):

```
void comp_geo::Calipers(int n, Point *p)
{
    rotatePoint = p[n];
    // or:
    // rotatePoint.Set_value(p[n]);
}
```

---

On a side note, `Point::Set_value(Point)` should be taking the `Point` by `const` reference instead of by value:

```
void Point::Set_value(const Point &p)
{
    x = p.x;
    y = p.y;
}
```

Comment: THIS.

I'm not even sure why I attempted to use a pointer. Thank you.

Comment: I tried calling this function in another function (Effectively tried to copy from p[] to rotatepoint[]. However, the copying only works if i break down the code into the main(). 

Is there any way to call Caliper() without the variables turning to zero when I printf?

Comment: @MarcoPang please [edit] your question to show the code that is not working for you. You are clearly still doing something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
void comp_geo::Calipers(int n, Point *p)
{
    double Cx = **&**p[n].x;
    double Cy = **&**p[n].y;
    rotatePoint.x = Cx;
    rotatePoint.y = Cy;`
}
```

The ampersand is not needed as it refers to the address of the memory location, rather than the value.

```
void comp_geo::Calipers(int n, Point *p)
{
    rotatePoint.x = p[n].x;
    rotatePoint.y = p[n].y;
}
```